# Rendering different HTML depending on value of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I wish to use C# and Razor syntax to check if a cookie has been set. If it has been set, I want to show

```
<h2> Cookie set </h2>.
```

If it hasn't, I want to display

```
<h2>Cookie not set</h2>
```

So, to review a few things, I have this setting the cookie :

```
//set cookie
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("stackOverflowCookie");
if(cookie == null) {
   cookie = new HttpCookie("stackOverflowCookie");
   cookie.Value = "Hi guys!";
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
   Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Using Razor, what is the best way, syntactically, to render what I wish? Whatever I try results in compilation errors :

```
@{
     if(Request.Cookies["stackOverflowCookie"] == null){ 
        //some other logic is here in my actual code, so an inline statement is not sufficient
        <h2> Cookie set </h2>
@}
@{ else {

<h2> Cookie not set </h2>

@}
```

Obviously this is horrible looking, and it doesn't work. It does show the functionality I would like those. How is the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your if statement logic is longer than a single-liner allows, you can just set a variable in a code block:

```
@{
    var isCookieSet = Request.Cookies["stackOverflowCookie"] == null && otherConditions;
}
```

And then your razor code could just look like this:

```
@if (isCookieSet) { 
    <h2>Cookie set</h2>
} else {
    <h2>Cookie not set</h2>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remember to be careful of putting logic in the user-interface (ie, the View).

You may wish to consider editing the View-Model to include a value of the cookie, and display the different UI depending on this variable using a simply IF statement:

```
@if(model.CookieProperty != null) {
  <h2>Cookie is set</h2>
} else {
  <h2>Cookie is not set</h2>
}
```

And then having the controller reading the cookie, and setting the View-Model property:

```
model.CookieProperty = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
```

The advantages of this are:

- The controller may need to "enable functionality" or perform other logic depending on this value
- Testing: It's difficult to test UI elements. Easy to test a View-Model.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
@if(Request.Cookies["stackOverflowCookie"] == null) { 
    <h2> Cookie set </h2>
} else {
    <h2> Cookie not set </h2>
}
```